# Is there any possible way to display data from different sensors received from serial port individually?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, sensors

So i am working on a rc car which is equipped with a gps module(NEOBLOX 6M) and a geiger counter(Diy Kit). The data read by sensors is to be displayed on a c# application using xbee modules. On my C# application i am using a label to be updated according to the data received, but the problem here is that the data from gps module and geiger counter both is displayed on a single label, i want to display data from different sensors on individual labels or textboxes.

GPS Module:http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=Ublox_NEO-6M_GPS_Module

Geiger Counter:https://www.ebay.com/p/US-Assembled-DIY-Geiger-Counter-Kit-Nuclear-Radiation-Detector-Arduino-Tube-2018/14014157093?iid=273049840938

Comment: this appears to be a general C# programming question that is not related to the Arduino

Answer (score 0):

Well have you heard the term ROS?

Your description isn`t very clear. So I dont have much idea on your system design.

No matter all the sensor is connected to arduino or partially connect to arduino and partial connect to PC.

You can use ROS Arduino node and ros node to read the sensor and publish with ROS-time.  You can follow the method in the link below

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);

char hello[13] = "hello world!";

void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  str_msg.data = hello;
  chatter.publish( &str_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

You can change this str_msgs to any msgs type that you sensor is giving, Eg giger counter is double. Or sensor_msgs/NavSatFix (gps message in ros) , or your position is nav_msgs/Odometry

Whenever there is a reading, just publish them with a correct time stamp.

Publish all the info to the C# ros node for display. Usually, there would be a lot of data, so you shouldnt use textboxes. Instead you should be able to plot a heat map or energy map

https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp  follow this for ROS C# interface

[image]